# Context scaling breaks some drawing

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to draw on a virtual canvas of proportions 1x1 so that I don't have to constantly multiply out the actual dimensions.

This works perfectly when I draw circles, but it would appear as though it does not work well with rectangles, and I'm not sure why.

When I have the following code:

```
var canvas = this.canvas;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(.5, .5, .1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
```

It works fine, and the circle scales with the canvas.

However, when I merely change it to the following:

```
var canvas = this.canvas;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0,0, .0001, .001);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(.5, .5, .1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
```

the rectangle takes up the entirety of the screen and even covers up the circle, even though the circle is drawn after the rectangle. It should, obviously, be taking up a very minute amount of space on the canvas.

It might be worth noting that this occurs in a game loop.

However, the following works as expected, with a red circle appearing above a blue backdrop

```
var canvas = this.canvas;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0,0, 50, 50);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(10, 10, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: I can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/k6VpE/ works just fine for me (I made the rectange a bit bigger so you can actually see it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling this repeatedly in a game loop, the `scale` method will increase the scale of your transform, *every time through the loop*. So you end up with everything growing. Since you're not showing your actual code, it's hard to tell why the circle isn't affected.

Try calling `scale()` only once, or use `save()` and `restore()`, or just reset the transform at the start of the loop, before calling `scale()`:

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Works brilliantly, thank you. I have a resize function, so I reset and scale the context when the dimensions change.